# Adding conditional columns to multi-level column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi-level column dataframe where I need to add a column (level_2) based on conditions in other columns.  The added column will be applied to all level_1 groups.  For example, the conditional column will be addded to A1, B1, C1, etc.  This dataframe is just an example of the larger dataframe I'm working on.  Level_1 is dynamic and can change, for example, adding Z1 or taking out B1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

level_1 = ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'B1', 'B1', 'B1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1']
level_2 = ['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1', 'a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1', 'a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']
data = [['a', 23, 'h', 'o', 45, 'v', 'a3', 1, 'b1'], ['b', 34, 'i', 'p', 3, 'w', 'a4', 32, 'b2'], ['c', 5, 'j', 'q', 7, 'x', 'a5', 6, 'b3'], ['d', 2, 'k', 'r', 5, 'y', 'a6', 76, 'b4'], ['e', 78, 'l', 's', 65, 'z', 'a7', 9, 'b5'], ['f', 98, 'm', 't', 23, 'a1',  'a8', 14, 'b6'], ['g', 3, 'n', 'u', 1, 'a2', 'a9', 45, 'b7']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(level_1, level_2)))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
date = ['1/1/2023','1/2/2023','1/3/2023','1/4/2023','1/5/2023','1/6/2023','1/7/2023']

df1.insert(0, 'date', date)

df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

I've tried the below code, which works, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, without looping?  Thank you.

```
for column_name in df1.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    df1.loc[(df1[column_name, 'b_1'] > 30) | (df1[column_name, 'a_1'] == 'c'), (column_name,'e_1')] = 1

df1 = df1.reindex(columns=['A1','B1','C1'], level=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way with reshaping. Stack the level=0 column values then assign the new column `e_1` based on the required condition, finally unstack to reshape back to original form

```
s = df1.stack(level=0)
s.loc[s['a_1'].eq('e') & s['b_1'].gt(30), 'e_1'] = 1
s = s.unstack().swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

---

```
          A1               B1              C1            
         a_1 b_1 c_1  e_1 a_1 b_1 c_1 e_1 a_1 b_1 c_1 e_1
date                                                     
1/1/2023   a  23   h  NaN   o  45   v NaN  a3   1  b1 NaN
1/2/2023   b  34   i  NaN   p   3   w NaN  a4  32  b2 NaN
1/3/2023   c   5   j  NaN   q   7   x NaN  a5   6  b3 NaN
1/4/2023   d   2   k  NaN   r   5   y NaN  a6  76  b4 NaN
1/5/2023   e  78   l  1.0   s  65   z NaN  a7   9  b5 NaN
1/6/2023   f  98   m  NaN   t  23  a1 NaN  a8  14  b6 NaN
1/7/2023   g   3   n  NaN   u   1  a2 NaN  a9  45  b7 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `.xs`?

```py
x = df1.xs('b_1', axis=1, level=1) > 30
y = df1.xs('a_1', axis=1, level=1).eq('c')
z = (x | y).astype(int)
z.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([z.columns, ['e_1']])

df1 = pd.concat([df1, z], axis=1).reindex(columns=['A1','B1','C1'], level=0)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
          A1              B1              C1            
         a_1 b_1 c_1 e_1 a_1 b_1 c_1 e_1 a_1 b_1 c_1 e_1
date                                                    
1/1/2023   a  23   h   0   o  45   v   1  a3   1  b1   0
1/2/2023   b  34   i   1   p   3   w   0  a4  32  b2   1
1/3/2023   c   5   j   1   q   7   x   0  a5   6  b3   0
1/4/2023   d   2   k   0   r   5   y   0  a6  76  b4   1
1/5/2023   e  78   l   1   s  65   z   1  a7   9  b5   0
1/6/2023   f  98   m   1   t  23  a1   0  a8  14  b6   0
1/7/2023   g   3   n   0   u   1  a2   0  a9  45  b7   1
```